# How to get selected items from changelist?

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie with python/django and have written a custom action called List wherein I display a html table showing the data.
It works if something is selected but shows all the items even though I have selected only a few of them.
I am trying to show only the items I selected in the html table but can't find how to do it.
My model is called Exchangerate and has the currencycodefrom,currencycodeto,effectivedate(PK) and conversionratemultiplier as the fields.
Here is ExchangerateAdmin:

```
class ExchangerateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        post = request.POST.copy()
        post.setlist(admin.helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME,
        self.model.objects.values_list('effectivedate', flat=True))
        request.POST = post
        #qs = self.model._default_manager.get_queryset()
        qs = super(ExchangerateAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(editors=request.user)
    actions = [export_csv,list,retrieve,]
```

and here is my code for the list action:

```
def list(self, request, queryset):
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

queryset = ExchangerateAdmin.get_queryset(self, request)
serializer = ExchangerateSerializer(queryset, many=True)
res = "<head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"C:/Django/django-django-2dcde52/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/donationsdue.css\" /></head>"
res += "<body bgcolor=\"#9E9E8A\" ><H1 style=\"color:#275858;text-align:center\">Exchange Rates</H1><br><table border='10' align=\"center\">"
res += "<tr><th  bgcolor=\"#4FDB00\">Currency To</th><th  bgcolor=\"#4FDB00\">Currency From</th><th  bgcolor=\"#4FDB00\">Effective Date YYYY-MM-DD</th><th  bgcolor=\"#4FDB00\">Conversion Multiplier</th></tr>"
count = 0
for item in serializer.data:
    thisitem = str(item)
    thisitem = thisitem[1:len(thisitem)-1]
    res += "<tr  bgcolor=\"#CEFF00\">"
    splitlist = thisitem.split("\n",)
    print splitlist[0]
    for line in splitlist:
        splitlist2 = str(line).split(":",)
        for line2 in splitlist2:
            if 'datetime.date'in line2:
                datestr = str(line2)[14:len(str(line2))]
                datestr = datestr[1:len(str(line2))-1]
                datelist = datestr.split(",",)
            splitlist3 = str(line2).split(",",)
            print splitlist3[0]

            print len(splitlist3[0])
            if 'u' in splitlist3[0]:
                splitlist3[0]=splitlist3[0][2:len(splitlist3[0])]    
            if 'datetime.date'in splitlist3[0]:
                splitlist3[0]=splitlist3[0][14:len(splitlist3[0])] 
                splitlist3[0]=splitlist3[0]+'-'+datelist[1].replace(' ','')+'-'+datelist[2].replace(' ','')
                splitlist3[0]=splitlist3[0][1:len(splitlist3[0])-1]
            if 'Decimal' in splitlist3[0]:
                splitlist3[0]=splitlist3[0][7:len(splitlist3[0])]
                splitlist3[0]=splitlist3[0][3:len(splitlist3[0])-2]
            if count%5>0:
                res+="<td>"+splitlist3[0]+"</td>"
            count+=1
            #res+="<td>"+smart_str(line)+"</td>"
    res+="</tr>"
res+="</body></table><input type=\"button\" value=\"Previous Page\" onClick=\"javascript:history.go(-1);\" />"
return HttpResponse(res)
```

I have Googled this for weeks and have not been able to do it.
Can anyone set me on the right path?

Comment: You are returning the queryset before filtering if the user is a superuser. Could be that you are logged in to the admin as a superuser?

Comment: Yes I believe I am the 'superuser' How do I filter it?

Comment: Remove these two lines

if request.user.is_superuser:
    return qs

Comment: OK I have done that, but I don't know how to filter the queryset so that it contains only the items I selected. What I wrote in my code is not working Here is what I have now.

Comment: class ExchangerateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        def get_queryset(self, request):
            post = request.POST.copy()
            post.setlist(admin.helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME,
            self.model.objects.values_list('effectivedate', flat=True))
            request.POST = post
            #qs = self.model._default_manager.get_queryset()
            qs = super(ExchangerateAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
            return qs.filter()

Comment: Sorry but I cannot use code block in comments

Comment: `class ExchangerateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        def get_queryset(self, request):
            post = request.POST.copy()
            post.setlist(admin.helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME,
            self.model.objects.values_list('effectivedate', flat=True))
            request.POST = post
            #qs = self.model._default_manager.get_queryset()
            qs = super(ExchangerateAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
            return qs.filter()`

Comment: OK I figured it out.All I had to do was leave the queryset in my List function alone and not try to get it from the ExchangerateAdmin.